# Threading target function runs only one loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I am trying to run a function in the background till some work is done in the main function and then finish the thread. I have implemented the threading logic in a separate class and the main in another file. But every time I run it the target function only seems to run once and then waits

Here is the main function

```
from ThreadRipper import *

thread_obj=ThreadRipper()
thread_obj.start_thread()
squish.snooze(10)
print("Main Continuing")
thread_obj.stop_thread()
```

And the implemented class is as follows

```
class ThreadRipper():

def __init__(self):
    lib_path="iCOMClient.dll"
    self.vx = IcomVx(lib_path)
    config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
    config.readfp(open("vx_logger_config.cfg"))
    self.vx.connect(config.get("icom","ip"), timeout_millis = 30000)
    self.t = threading.Thread(target=self.task_to_do, args=(self.vx,))

def stop_thread(self):
    self.t.do_run=False
    self.t.join()

def start_thread(self):
    self.t.start()


def task_to_do(self,arg):
    current_thread=threading.currentThread()
    while getattr(current_thread,"do_run",True):
        with open("vx.txt",'a') as f:
            f.write(str(arg.get_next_message()._rawmsg)+"\n")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Stopping")
        arg.disconnect()
```

When I run this I get the vx file created but with only one entry, I expect it to be written to continuously till the while loop exits. I am quite new at threading and may have understood it incorrectly. Please advise

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably because

```
    print("Stopping")
    arg.disconnect()
```

are both inside the while loop. After disconnecting, `arg` doesn't seem to produce any more messages.

(Unless, of course, your code in the question is not what you really have, but in this case, you surely would have edited your question so it matches.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @glglgl,Yes I tried after moving  print("Stopping")
    arg.disconnect() outside the while loop but the same result.